# Trying to grasp the concept of cascading dropdowns

Tags: php, jquery, html

I am trying to understand the concept of how to utilize cascading dropdowns in a php script using jquery.  I am able to get the first dropdown to populate but not the second.

The first dropdown contains the customer id and name for customers in the mysql database.
The second dropdown contains the customers instruments they are linked with the customer id being a foriegn key in the instruments table.

Can anyone look at the code and tell me where I might be going astray?

This is the index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<title>Chained Select Tutorial</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2 /jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<?php
include('dbconnect.php');
$con=mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$db);
// An array of options for the first select box.
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM customers ORDER BY Customer Asc ");

// Displays the posted info 
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{ echo '<pre>'; print_r($_POST); echo '</pre>'; }
?>
<form action="" method="post">
<select id="cust" name="cust"><!-- Make sure to give the select box a id, this will make it much easier to target with jquery. -->
<?php
// Build the options for the first select box
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ echo '<option value="'.$row[Cust_ID].'">'.$row[Customer].'</option>'; }
?>
</select>
<select id="models" name="models"><!-- Make sure to give the select box a id, this will make it much easier to target with jquery. -->
</select>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<script>
$('#cust').change(function(){ //Basically saying when the first select box changes values run the function below.
var cust = $(this).val(); // Grab the value of the selection to send to the select-request.php via ajax
$.post('select-request.php', {cust:cust}, function(data){ // Run a ajax request and send the var make as a post variable named "make" and return the info in the "data" var.
    $('#models').html(data); // Have jquery change the html within the second select box with the "data" we got back from the ajax request.
});
});
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

and this is select-request.php

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL); //Remove this line for production, it simply will allow php to display any errors


//We check to see if the "cust" post has come through before we do any processing.
if(isset($_POST['cust']))
{ 
$con=mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$db); 
$result1 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT Inst_Name FROM instruments WHERE Cust_ID='$_POST[cust]'");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)){ echo '<option value="'.$row[Inst_Name].'">'.$row[Inst_Name].'</option>';

 }
?>
```

Can anyone please tell me where I have gone astray?

Comment: Have you included `dbconnect.php` in your `select-request.php` file? You should also enable error display and check the exact response in the console.

Comment: I did not have dbconnect included in select-request.php.  I have now included it but to no avail still no results.

Comment: Any messages in the console? You have not put your javascript in a document-ready section so you might get errors that jQuery is not defined yet.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the problem is with the php mysql as this is from a tutorial where if the arrays for the dropdowns are defined (not pulled from the database) this works

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the output on your console, I am guessing that jQuery is taking the first row as the output from your php script. In other words, it is only receiving the first ... that select-request.php is echoing. Try this:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)){ 
  $returnable .= '<option value="'.$row[Inst_Name].'">'.$row[Inst_Name].'</option> ';
}
echo json_encode($returnable);
```